# Hover out when mouse goes over the gap between absolute element and the parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 elements, an *outer* and an *inner*.

The *inner* element is positioned absolutely and leaves **a gap** between it and its parent (the *outer*).

I am using jQuery `.hover()` to show the *inner* element when the *outer* element gets hovered.

But because of the absolute positioned **when the mouse goes over the gap** its triggering the hover out. How can I avoid this?

Here is the [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VYSFv/1/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.outer {
    background: green;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px
}

.inner {
    background: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```javascript
$('.outer').hover(function () {
    $('.inner').show();
}, function () {
    $('.inner').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a pure CSS solution, you could fill the gap between `.inner` and `.outer` elements by using a **transparent** `border-top` for the `.inner`.

And use the [`background-clip: padding-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) CSS declaration in order to prevent the `background` from going behind the `border`:

```css
.inner {
    background-color: red;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    height: 100px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;                          /* Visual top value ---      */
                                                               |
    border-top: 100px solid transparent; /*   200px + 100px = 300px
                                               |        |
                          The real top value ---        --- The gap   */
    display: none;
}
```

Then use either [the jQuery `.hover()` method](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/VYSFv/11/) or CSS `:hover` pesudo-class to display the `.inner` element, as follows

```css
.outer:hover .inner {
    display: block;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/VYSFv/10/)**.

Comment: perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

You can add a timeout to delay hide a bit. During this delay, user can skip the gap with his mouse.

If you need an example, just tell me :)

Comment: I dont think timeout would be good as it makes the users action dependent on time instead of the movement

Comment: If it doesn't work with you, when you need to add some element with the same background in the gap. There no other possibilities.